# How can I sort an array of hashes by the hashes name?

Tags: perl

I want to sort an array of hashes by the hashes key, how could I do that in Perl?
The structure is created like this :

`push (@{$structure[$endpoint][1]}, \%temp_hash);`
`%temp_hash` is a simple hash with `key->value`.
And now I want to sort that array by the hashes key, there is only one key->value in each hash... been fighting with it for 2 hours already and I gave up..

Comment: Please show a full but minimal example that demonstrates what you've already tried and isn't working.

Comment: Pull the array out (just for easier syntax), then `my @sorted = sort { (keys %$a)[0] cmp (keys %$b)[0] } @arr;`. It seems a little awkward to have a single-pair hash in an array ... which is probably why you hava a problem. You can use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) or [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) or similiar to easily see complex data structures like this (it prints them out nicely). Please read up on [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).  And please next time show what you've done before you "_gave up_"

Comment: @zdim will this work on the same `@arr`? What I mean is will this work if i say something like this : 1@arr = sort { (keys %$a)[0] cmp (keys %$b)[0] } @arr;` ?

Comment: @zdim Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it will, it will overwrite the `@arr`.  However, that wouldn't update the reference in your `$structure`.  For that, get the input list directly from it, like in [Jim Garrison answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42425595/4653379) and assign (the reference of it) back to where it goes in `$structure`.  You can take a reference on the fly by `[ sort ... ]`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@sorted = sort {  (keys %$a)[0] cmp (keys %$b)[0] } @{$structure[$endpoint][1]};
```

This sorts the elements of the array (which are hash references) according to the first (only) key of each hash.  If the keys are numeric use `<=>` instead.

Test code:

```
%a = ( 'a' => 1 );
%b = ( 'zz' => 2 );
%c = ( 'g' => 3);
@arr = (\%a, \%b, \%c);

print "Unsorted\n";
for (@arr)
{
    printf "%s\n",((keys %$_)[0]);
}

@sorted = sort { (keys %$a)[0] cmp (keys %$b)[0] } @arr;

print "\nSorted\n";
for (@sorted)
{
    printf "%s\n",((keys %$_)[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can I store it in the same array?
`@{$structure[$endpoint][1]} = sort {  (keys %$a)[0] cmp (keys %$b)[0] } @{$structure[$endpoint][1]};`

Comment: What I mean is that I want to keep the structure and sort it

Comment: You can assign it back to the same variable, yes.

Comment: @Adrian yes, of course. `@arr = sort { ... } @arr` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Please make sure that example programs in your answer include `use strict` and `use warnings` and compile with both pragmata turned on. We're trying very hard to keep the quality up here so that future readers learn how to use Perl in a modern fashion. Thanks. :)